# Space and time complexity of operation on lists

Tags: optimization, beginner, haskell, functional-programming, complexity

I'm new to programming and even more new to Haskell.  Below is a little tid-bit I wrote that operates on a bunch of lists. I am wondering if someone would be kind enough to walk through the function `margProbs` line-by-line, and enumerate their respective space/time complexities and/or just possibly suggest improvements.

```
import qualified Control.Monad as Mo
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.List as L
import Data.Maybe

type PaIdx = Int

margProbs :: [[Bool]] -> PaIdx ->  [Double] -> [[Double]] -> Maybe [[Double]]
margProbs bs idx vpa vs = Mo.sequence $ fmap (\( _, ms ) -> collapseWith addV ms ) grouped
    where
        (p, q)   = ( vpa !! 0, vpa !! 1 )
        grouped  = reverse . sortAndGroup $ zip ( snd probBool ) scaled
        scaled   = zipWith (\p v -> scaleV (*) p v ) ( fst probBool ) vs
        probBool = foldr   (\b (probs, bools) -> let (prob,bool) = reducePa b in (prob:probs, bool:bools) ) ([],[]) bs
        reducePa bs = let split = fromJust $ pluckL idx bs in ( if fst split == True then p else q, snd split )


------------
-- Utils --
------------

addV :: ( Num a ) => [a] ->  [a] -> Maybe [a]
addV v1 v2 = if length v1 == length v2 then Just $ zipWith (+) v1 v2 else Nothing

scaleV :: (  Num a ) => ( a -> a -> a ) -> a -> [a] -> [a] 
scaleV g num v = fmap (\e -> g num e ) v

collapseWith :: ( Num a ) => ( [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a] ) -> [[a]] -> Maybe [a]
collapseWith g vs = foldr (\v1 v2 -> v2 >>= \w -> g v1 w ) ( return $ head vs ) ( tail vs )

sortAndGroup :: Ord k => [ (k, a) ] -> [ (k, [a]) ]
sortAndGroup ts = M.toList $ M.fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- ts]

pluckL :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe ( a, [a] )
pluckL idx xs = case splitAt idx xs of 
    ( _, [] )      -> Nothing
    ( hs, (t:ts) ) -> Just ( t, hs ++ ts )
```

Here are the params I used to test this snippet:

```
ret = margProbs bs 0 v m 
bs = [[True,True],[True,False],[False,True],[False,False]]
v = [0.4,0.6]
m = [[0.95,0.05], [0.94,0.06], [0.29,0.71], [0.1, 0.9]]
```

`ret` should have value: `Just [[0.554,0.446],[0.436,0.564]]`

**Update**

I got rid of all dependencies to the hmatrix library.

Comment: What do you expect as an answer: suggestions to improve  performance or just analysis of space&time complexity?

Comment: Analysis of space/time complexity would be great but if simple suggestions would take less of your time, that'd be great too

Answer (score 1):

**`scaleV`**

`scaleV` is very similar to `fmap`, it just has different precedence in its arguments, the following definition is simpler and highlights this similarity:

```
scaleV = (fmap .)
```

**Guards**

While they have the same effect of conditionals, they are preferred because they are extensible and nicer to read:

```
addV v1 v2 = if length v1 == length v2 then Just $ zipWith (+) v1 v2 else Nothing
```

Becomes:

```
addV v1 v2 
  | length v1 == length v2 = Just $ zipWith (+) v1 v2
  | otherwise = Nothing
```